# CSV file not recognised

Tags: csv

I am creating a CSV file in my system and MFT to another. When they receive it, their job does not pick up the file. When they open the file in excel, save it locally and reload the same file, the job picks up the records. I can't figure out what could be wrong with the file I create or something wrong with their job? Anyone experienced something similar?
Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With such a few details no one rather than you can find what's wrong.

My suggestion would be to get two files: one - the original file that the job does not want to deal with; second - the file that the job can consume (saved via Excel). Then open this two files in a notepad and try to find any differences.

Comment: Hi Sergey I have already done that and WinDiff does not pickup differences. CSV file is created by Java.

Comment: This sounds weird. If there's no difference in a files then try to manually "feed" the job with your original file.Check if that works.

Comment: I think it might be about line breaks of the file. When the file is opened with Excel, resaved and opened with NotePad, lines are formatted. When Java creates the file, when the output opened in NotePad, they are not line separated, even though I have /n. how can I make sure they are line formatted in Java?

Comment: I'm not really a Java guy but try "\r\n" or better System.lineSeparator()

Comment: Hi.. Issue solved. we were using /n and it wasn't creating new line.. replaced with /r/n and good to go